# How can I edit my Git config?

Tags: macos, git, config

I feel like this issue has been addressed before, but I couldn't find it after search through a bunch of posts.

I am doing a beginner's tutorial on Git. Someone had this Mac before me and used multiple Git Applications (SourceTree, etc) that seem to have added all kinds of config preferences.

When I type `git config --list`, I get an enormous list (shown below), unlike the tutorial that I am watching on Lynda.com where the author only shows a list of user.name and user.email.

```
core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore
core.legacyheaders=false
core.quotepath=false
core.pager=less -r
mergetool.keepbackup=true
push.default=simple
color.ui=auto
color.interactive=auto
repack.usedeltabaseoffset=true
alias.s=status
alias.a=!git add . && git status
alias.au=!git add -u . && git status
alias.aa=!git add . && git add -u . && git status
alias.c=commit
alias.cm=commit -m
alias.ca=commit --amend
alias.ac=!git add . && git commit
alias.acm=!git add . && git commit -m
alias.l=log --graph --all --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%C(cyan)%d%Creset %s %C(white)- %an, %ar%Creset'
alias.ll=log --stat --abbrev-commit
alias.lg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%h%Creset -%C(bold green)%d%Creset %s %C(bold green)(%cr)%Creset %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
alias.llg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%H %d%Creset%n%s%n%+b%C(bold blue)%an <%ae>%Creset %C(bold green)%cr (%ci)' --abbrev-commit
alias.d=diff
alias.master=checkout master
alias.spull=svn rebase
alias.spush=svn dcommit
alias.alias=!git config --list | grep 'alias\.' | sed 's/alias\.\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/\1\     => \2/' | sort
include.path=~/.gitcinclude
include.path=.githubconfig
include.path=.gitcredential
diff.exif.textconv=exif
credential.helper=osxkeychain
mergetool.sourcetree.cmd=--null
user.name=username
user.email=email
```

Ultimately, I would like to remove all of these additional settings. I tried uninstalling Git, but that didn't make a difference. Is there a command to undo all of these? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Git configuration is spread across up to three config files (one for each *level*).
You can edit your config (add/remove entries) by editing those files, or by using the right `git-config` commands (more robust, but possibly more tedious). The problem is simply to locate which part of your config is located in which config file. Instead of running

```
git config --list
```

which lists the contents of all three files (i.e. your *entire* Git configuration), you can run three different commands for listing the contents of each of those three config files.

- **System-level** config file

  Usually located at `/usr/local/etc/gitconfig`; at least, that's where mine is on my Mac (I installed Git with Homebrew). You can list its contents by running:

  ```
  git config --system --list
  ```
- **User-level** config file

  Usually located at `$HOME/.gitconfig`. You can list its contents by running:

  ```
  git config --global --list
  ```
- **Repository-level** config file

  Usually located at `<repo-root-folder>/.git/config`. You can list its contents by running:

  ```
  git config --local --list
  ```

If you only want to retain the `user.name` and `user.email` fields from your current config and get rid of all the rest, the easiest thing is to delete all three config files and then simply run

```
git config --global user.name <your-name>
git config --global user.email <your-email>
```

(The `user.name` and `user.email` fields are most commonly set in the user-level config file.)

Comment: That's what I needed! I was able to narrow it down to the right file that way and find the lines that I needed to get rid of! Thanks!